# Finding the joint conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve the following task:

Let $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ with $\lambda>0$ and $Y$ a random variable in $\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that for $n>$ the law of $Y$ given $X=n$ is $B(n,p)$ and that $Y=0$ if $X=0$.

1) Compute the join law of $(X,Y)$

What I did so far:

We know that for $n>0$ we have $$P(Y\leq n|X=n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nP(Y=k|X=n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
So this means $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^nP(Y=k|X=n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{P(Y=k,X=n)}{P(X=n)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{n!e^{\lambda}}{\lambda^n }P(Y=k,X=n)$$

So we have $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{n!e^{\lambda}}{\lambda^n }P(Y=k,X=n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Now the joint law would be $P(Y\leq n, X\leq t)$, now how can I find this?

Comment: Why not compute directly $P(X=n,Y=k)=P(X=n)P(Y=k\mid X=n)$ for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$? This is what you are asked to do, in the end, and it is simpler than the computations you embarked yourself in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $q:=1-p$ we have for $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$:

$\Pr\left(Y=k\wedge X=n\right)=\Pr\left(Y=k\mid X=n\right)\Pr\left(X=n\right)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\left(\lambda p\right)^{k}\left(\lambda q\right)^{n-k}}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}$

If $k\notin\left\{ 0,\dots,n\right\} $ then the probability takes
value $0$.